# How to query in Monogdb when JSON contain \ and not in proper format?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is a MongoDB document in which I try to get "ID" and "Node 2", but I can't get values ​​from it.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5deb99b8cfee8a21b0bd7500"),
"topic" : "outTopic",
"value" : "{ \"Reading No\": \" 3885 \",\"ID\":\" 946\", \"node 2\": \"20.00 *C\"} ",
"time" : ISODate("2019-12-07T17:53:20.744Z")
}
```

below queries, I tried.

```
db.collection.find({"topic":"outTopic","value.ID":"884"}).count(); #output 0

0r

db.collection.find({"topic":"outTopic","value":{"ID":"884"}}).count(); #output 0
```

Comment: If you control the writing of the data then try to serialise `value` properly before it gets saved in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already trying this way, but the above-mentioned data is too large inside mongodb and for that, I require a mongo-query to fetch ID and Node 2

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$regex` operator to find a substring:

```
db.collection.find({
  "topic": "outTopic",
  "value": {
    $regex: "\"ID\":\"9463440403\""
  }
})
```

Hope that helps!